# How do I make specific tones with a piezo buzzer?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, piezo, buzzer

I am using a piezo buzzer and fiddling around with it a little bit. I currently have different tones with delays in between and I have to do a lot of trial and error for the piezo buzzer to play sounds like I want it to. Is there a better way to do this? because at this rate I will be stuck for a while.

I am trying to get the piezo buzzer to make the sound of an alarm. Any suggestion on how I can get it to sound exactly like an alarm or is trial and error the only way?

Comment: Posting your current code, might help us to better understand what it is you want to achieve (better).

Comment: are you using an active or passive buzzer? (they need different code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to know from your question what you are having trouble with.  I have a piano and I can hit the keys, but it takes me a long time to hit them in the right order and with the right timings to create a new symphony.

Anyway, if creating the sounds is the problem, have you looked at the [Tone library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone)?

Different alarms have different sounds.  I once heard an alarm which sounded like the start of [Fuer Elise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mVW8tgGY_w), so probably the [notes](http://makingmusicfun.net/images/thumbs/fur-elise.jpg) were `E` and `D#`.  That would make their [frequencies](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html) about 330Hz and 311Hz:

```
void loop()
{
    tone(pin, 330, 250);
    delay(300);
    tone(pin, 311, 250);
    delay(300);
}
```

The sound you [linked to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo4yJbjkMWA) sounds to me like it starts on a C, and slides up gradually one octave.  One octave higher is double the frequency, so this code should do that:

```
void loop()
{
    const int startFreq = 523;  // C5 is 523Hz

    // Start at the given freqency, and increase gradually by
    // one octave (double the frequency)
    for (int freq=startFreq ; freq<= (startFreq*2) ; ++freq)
    {
        tone(pin, freq, 10);
        delay(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said I want to make the piezo buzzer implement an alarm. However, I need to have right tones. I have to find this right tone, and its hard for me to get there. maybe there is an easier way to implement the type of sound you are wanting to produce. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: What is the pin? because its not declared in the scope?

Comment: It's the pin number that you have the buzzer on. You could find that out by reading the links in my post, and you would learn much more than by copying and pasting code you don't understand.

Comment: A specific alarm I was looking for was like a fire alarm

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo4yJbjkMWA like this one

Comment: That sounds to me like it's starting on a C and sliding up one octave. See if you can write code to do that. If you can't, I'll do it tomorrow when I'm on a proper computer. Do you have the `tone` library working and generating sounds?

Comment: Yes I do have the tone library. Thank you very much I'll let you know if I get it done

Comment: Nah mate, tried to get there today (was close) but I was still doing the same trial and error. If you can help me out, that'd be great thanks.

Comment: hmm..I don't know why but the piezo makes no sound. Maybe if I put the code and the circuir in the post, you might see why?

Comment: You can see for yourself https://circuits.io/circuits/4202932-the-unnamed-circuit/edit

Comment: Does it make no sound ever, or only with my code?  Please include in your question example code, using the `tone` library, with which it makes *some* sound, because I don't know what I'm debugging here.

Comment: Well for my particular code (which I have provided you the circuit and the code) I have not used the tone libraby. Why is it that the library must be included. I have used the piezo before with other projects which made sound just fine... I think its the problem with the for loop, because I removed it and kept the other lines and it produced sound, still not the way I wanted it to sound like :/.

Comment: It's alright. I don't want to be nagging. This is not a homework site so i'll just let it pass. Thanks for all that you could offer.